# Is there a way to get the sonar result per class or per module

Tags: python, sonarqube

I want to get the sonar result in the class wise classification or modularized format. I am using python and the sonar web API. Apart from the basic APIs are there any other APIs which give me the results per class

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube doesn't know the concept of "class". This is a logical element, whereas SonarQube manages only "physical" components like files or folders. The consequence is that the Web API allows you to query only components that are "physical".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. As I am new to sonar can you please suggest me any link which has an example for the component API..

Comment: You can see the documentation online on your SonarQube instance. For instance, you can see it on SonarQube.com at https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/components